# How to dynamically create a python function within a module?

Tags: python-3.x, function, import, exec

I wrote a function `def_function`, that dynamically defines another function at runtime.

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def def_function(name):
  lines = list()
  lines.append('global {}\n'.format(name))
  lines.append('def {}():\n'.format(name))
  lines.append('  print(\'{}() has been called!\')\n'.format(name))
  code = ''.join(lines)
  function = compile(code, '', 'exec')
  exec(function)

def_function('foo')
foo()
```

Running **main.py** gives the expected output:

> foo() has been called!

Now I'd like to move the definition of `def_function` to `module.py` and import it from `main.py`.

**module.py**

```
def def_function(name):
  lines = list()
  lines.append('global {}\n'.format(name))
  lines.append('def {}():\n'.format(name))
  lines.append('  print(\'{}() has been called!\')\n'.format(name))
  code = ''.join(lines)
  function = compile(code, '', 'exec')
  exec(function)
```

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from module import def_function

def_function('foo')
foo()
```

This results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 6, in <module>
    foo()
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

I've already googled my problem and read various questions at SO, but I couldn't find a solution. Please help me.

Comment: Did you know that you can write nested function definitions in Python?

Comment: I know, but as far as I understand the code of a nested function can't be generated at runtime. My real function generates code depending on further arguments to `def_function`.

Comment: *all* functions in Python are created at runtime! (Except the built-in ones which are not written with `def ...`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `foo` in `module.py` scope. Do not forget import `module.py`.

Call `foo()`, as `module.foo()`.

```
import module

module.def_function('foo')
module.foo()
```

May help you https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/

**Additional**

Add this after `exec(function)`. Also import `sys`.

```
setattr(sys.modules['__main__'], name, globals()[name])
```

Setattr it's function assigns the value to the attribute of object or create new attribute.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr

**module.py**

```
import sys


def def_function(name):
    lines = list()
    lines.append('global {}\n'.format(name))
    lines.append('def {}():\n'.format(name))
    lines.append('  print(\'{}() has been called!\')\n'.format(name))
    code = ''.join(lines)
    function = compile(code, '', 'exec')
    exec(function)
    setattr(sys.modules['__main__'], name, globals()[name])
```

**main.py**

```
from module import def_function

def_function('foo')
foo()
```

Comment: Thanks for the possible workaround/solution. Is there a way to define `foo` in the global scope from within `module.py`?

Comment: @DnsLnk Yes, you can.

Comment: Honestly, there are other ways to solve this, but more context is needed.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info! Thats exactly what I was looking for.
I will upvote your answer, as soon as I have sufficient reputation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your example can be written like this, with a nested function definition and no `compile` or `exec`:

```
def def_function(name):
    def f():
        print(name, "has been called")
    return f

# ...

foo = def_function("foo")
```

You have to return it, however.

Comment: Thanks but if I knew the code of `foo` before runtime, then I would just define it like any other function. My real `def_function` contains various `if`s, `else`s and loops and generates `foo` depending on further arguments. I don't think that can be done with a nested function definition. I might be wrong though.